# Facebook JAR contains confused image

Tags: android, facebook

I have an app in android and it's using the facebook sdk to post a `stream.publish`

The user needs to login to facebook before the post can be made so they get the login prompt which is supposed to have a rounded close button at the top left corner.

The problem is that the default facebook close image is showing up as another image in from the app (an image we made) and we have no idea why that's happening. I even tried changing the image in the facebook jar and tried finding the close button in the jar's login layout folder (couldn't find the layout I wanted).

How do I even go about debugging an issue like this?

Comment: "another image" means that there's an image from your drawable folder showing up at the top left corner instead of the 'x'-close image?

Comment: Yep. I made an edit to hopefully make that a bit more clear.

Comment: For starters, do a "clean" on every project involved and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: did a clean and no go. I also had a friend run the code on his machine and he's seeing the same thing. ps I'm running my code on a device (samsung).

Comment: What is the name of your drawable which is visible instead of close button?

Answer (score 0):

This is working now but the project is not using the JAR anymore. The latest facebook implementation is to add the facebook code as another eclipse project and import it to your application. Viola.